# dynamic create json for treeview

Tags: json, dynamic, treeview

I want to turn json

```
var treeNodes = [ {managerid:root,Employeeid:01}, 
                  {managerid:01,Employeeid:11}, 
                  {managerid:01,Employeeid:22}, 
                  {managerid:22,Employeeid:33}, 
                  {managerid:22,Employeeid:44} 
                ];
```

into json like this using javascript.

```
json={
  id:root,
  children[{
       id:01,
       children[
               {id:11},
               {id:22}
       ]
       children[
               {id:33},
               {id:44}
       ]
 }
```

Can someone help with java script function?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your current JSON is incorrect:

```
var json = {
   id: root, 
   children: [
         { 
            id: 01,
            children: [
               {id: 11},
               {id: 22} 
            ]
         }, 
         {
            children: [
               {id: 33},
               {id: 44} 
            ]
         }
      ]
   };
```

Second, could you give more information about your table `Employee`?

Comment: it actually json like this sorry, somehow it not line up right. 

var treeNodes = [
    {managerid:root,Employeeid:01},
    {managerid:01,Employeeid:11},
    {managerid:01,Employeeid:22},
    {managerid:22,Employeeid:33},
    {managerid:22,Employeeid:44}
];